# Printing datainput in form by Ajax Request not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a form, which on submit goes to a php file (save.php) and echoes the name back, which after taken as response is alerted in the index.html. Somehow I cannot print back the name which was send to php. Pls help.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit1').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "save.php",
                    data: jQuery("#form1").serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success:  function(data){
                       /* alert(data); if json obj. alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
                       alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div class="form_wrapper">
    <form id="form1">
        Name:<input id="name1" type="text" /> <br/>
        Email:<input id="email1" type="email" /><br/>
        <input id="submit1" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
echo $name;

?>
```

Kindly, help!

ERROR:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\example3\save.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: email1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\example3\save.php on line 4
```

Comment: Do you have any error? (If you include `error: function(){}`)

Comment: Error in php file line 3 & 4 - Notice: Undefined index: name1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\example3\save.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: email1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\example3\save.php on line 4

Comment: Can you post your HTML? As it shows that `name1` and `email1` don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your input feild a **name** and access `$_POST['given_name']` in php

Thank you :)

Comment: fo eg:   `Name:<input id="name1" name="name1" type="text" /> <br/>` in `html` and `echo $_POST['name1'];` in php

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your inputs don't have the `name` attribute with the `name1` and `email1`.

```
Name:<input id="name1" name="name1" type="text" /> <br/>
Email:<input id="email1" name="email1" type="email" /><br/
```

Comment: Can u tell what if I have to print echo($name+" "+$email) ?? This is returning '0', though otherwise it is returning single variable like only $name or $email?

Comment: It should be `echo $name . " " . $email;`

Comment: `echo` doesn't use brackets and string concatenation in PHP use dots(.) not plus(+).

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the name of the input field

```
 Name:<input id="name1" type="text" name="name1"/> <br/>
 Email:<input id="email1" type="email" name="email"/><br/>
```